# Unit testing a binarysearchtree

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, testing, tree

lets say you have this binary search tree (BST). See code below. Properties:

- The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node’s key.
- The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node’s key.
- Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

How would you unit test it? You can't access the nodes and can't verify the structure. You can't test the Insert function separately.

1) You can create an inherited test class from BST and declare extra methods to be able to test. Is this common?

2) Implement the BST differently. Have a Tree class. This class can access child nodes etc. and implements basic tree functionality. Inherit BST from Tree. Test BST with the help of methods provided by Tree.

3) Your opinion?

Thank you.

```
template <typename ValueType>
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:

    BinarySearchTree() : m_count(0), m_root(nullptr) {}
    void Insert(const ValueType& elementToInsert);
    bool Remove(const ValueType& elementToRemove);
    bool Contains(const ValueType& elementToFind);
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    size_t Count() const;
    ValueType Max() const;
    ValueType Min() const;
    int Delimiter() const;
    void PrintToFile(std::ofstream& outFile);
    void BuildFromFile(std::ifstream& inFile);
    ~BinarySearchTree() { delete m_root; }
    // TODO: copy ctr, copy assignment operator, move ctr

private:

    struct Node
    {
        Node(const ValueType& value) : value(value), parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
        ~Node() { delete left; delete right; }
        // TODO: copy ctr, copy assignment operator, move ctr

        ValueType value;
        Node* parent;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    Node* m_root;
    int m_count;
};
```

Comment: Really interesting question! But, unfortunately, I think it would be close because too broad... But, IMHO, you have to test it as a black box: you input stimuli via insert, remove,... and use accessors to view what he has. Another solution is to use some unit test libraries which instrument your code to allow access to private field

Comment: John Lakos (of the c++ std committee) wrote a book once upon a time about [Large Scale C++ Design](https://www.amazon.com/Large-Scale-Software-Design-John-Lakos/dp/0201633620). It talks extensively about designing for testability, you should grab it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the lines of common STL implementations, I'd split your `BinarySearchTree` class into different components:

- Some binary tree class that only works with nodes. Lets name it `BinaryTree`. It supports insertion and removal of `Node *`, traversal (`begin` and `end`) and useful tree manipulations (like `rotate` for balancing the tree). But it won't allocate anything or find anything (no `ValueType` known).
- A specific binary tree version that guarantees `log(n)` depth. Let's call it `AVLTree` (you can also go with red black or something else). This tree is aware of the `ValueType` and will implement methods like `find` and insertion / deletion for values (including the memory management). It will also take care of the balancing based on the values stored.

(On top of that, you could then build something like `set` or `map` like the STL does it.)

**Benefits for testing:**

The `BinaryTree` class would be templated in the `Node` type used in the tree (templated over polymorphic `virtual` method based for reasons of performance). Hence for unit testing, you could build a `BinaryTree` with different types of `Nodes`. Those special types of nodes can maintain additional information (eg. counters) for your tests (eg. the left child changes at most once during some operation).

On the other hand, the `AVLTree` is only testable based on values, eg. some value can be found after insertion. That's basically the same as for your original `BinarySearchTree`. I'd recommend adding some testing method (eg. `verify_invariants`) that iterates the complete tree and checks all your invariants (eg. `log(n)` depth, father of child of node is node). This might be costly and slow, but should only be used for your unit tests.

---

Just a closing remark: If you write your tree for yourself / an assignment - fine! If this should be used somewhere in the "real" world on the other hand, strongly consider using an STL container instead.

Comment: Thanks. I like very much the first part of you answer, about how to implement and test BinaryTree with special types of Nodes.

Comment: About the second part. Wouldn't it be better to implement and use methods of BinaryTree to access the left, right child, the parent, and verify the relations of the structure of the BinarySearchTree with these?

Comment: You mean within `verify_invariant`? Certainly yes. But that is the only place. Other tests / users from the outside won't have access to the tree...

Comment: No no, I mean to skip `verify_invariant` and use a `BinaryTree` pointer pointing to a `BinarySearchTree` and access the nodes of the  `BinarySearchTree` with methods of `BinaryTree` in the tests.

Comment: But how do you initialize that `BinaryTree` pointer? You don't want to expose your tree members ...

Comment: Sure.. There were some misconceptions in my mind.